# DB Caching: Where exactly is it happening?

Tags: sql, database, caching

When a change is "not yet committed" to the DB, where exactly is that info stored? Is it in some temporary table? Written to a file? Or directly in RAM?

Comment: It could be anywhere; it would be implementation-dependent.

Comment: Almost certainly in memory, obviously. It doesn't need to be a temp table, it can just be the data, or the SQL, or...?

Comment: Hmm but can a database have memory?

Comment: @KishoreE, a database engine most certainly leverages memory. SQL Server for example is heavily RAM dependent to do its job.

Comment: A database is just software. Most software uses memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, the DBMS will put the requested changes in a kind of "queue" in memory, but also write these changes to permanent storage (disk) in the background. At the same time, it's keeping track of what has changed, in case a ROLLBACK is needed.

Having the in-memory queue minimizes blocking on each individual SQL command, yet not waiting too long before writing changes to permanent storage minimizes blocking on COMMIT<sup>1</sup>.

That's the reason why one larger transaction tends to be faster than a bunch of smaller ones - it gives the DBMS more chance to do things in the background, before being forced to block the client on COMMIT.

---

*<sup>1</sup> A "D" in "ACID transaction" stands for ["durable"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID#Durability), which essentially means that when transaction COMMITs, its effects are guaranteed to already be in permanent storage (and not just in volatile memory that can be lost in case of power failure or other problem).*

Answer (score 1):

This is RDBMS dependent. As an example, I'll discuss SQL Server: uncommitted writes are made directly on the live data. The changes might also end up flushed on disk. At the same time a transaction log item documents the changes so that they can be rolled back or rolled forward.

Uncommitted changes are not at all dependent on memory "caches" or write buffers. They can be written at any time and still be undone later.

Comment: The cache is in memory. It does not necessarily mirror exactly what's on disk because writes are flushed lazily. The transaction log ensures that this is always 100% safe.